# File transfer between 2 vmware workstations on same host

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, virtual-machine, vmware, ftp-client

I need to transfer a file from **`aProcess1`** on a **`VM1`** inside a VmWare Workstation to another **`VM2`** inside the same VmWare Workstation hypervisor **on the same host**, so as to calculate the ***rate of data transfer*** between these 2 virtual machines.

1. Either to write a FTP server client server program, then how to calculate time..?
2. And also how to manage the ports in virtual machines (let's say on both Ubuntu is working ) 
   in writing server client program..?

Comment: Why develop anything? There are plenty of existing resources: iperf, FTP servers and clients, SFTP servers and clients, etc.

Comment: Actually I am trying to analys the provisioning of RAM to virtual machines for cloud computation, for that purpose I need to get data tranfer rate in 2 virtual machines

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is not trivial and you'll have to invest some effort. First of all you need to create a bridge between the two VMs and have each VM with a tap interface on that bridge.

I have a script below you can look at as an example - it creates some screen sessions (you will need a basic .screenrc) and I launch a VM in each screen tab. Really the bit that should only interest you is the bridge setup and how to launch qemu.

Networking setup you want static routes - the below is an example of what I had with eth0 being a user network interface and eth1 being the interface connected to the peer VM. You could get rid of eth0. The peer VM route was a mirror of this

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
  up route add default gw 10.0.2.2 eth0
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 20.0.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 20.0.0.0
  broadcast 20.0.0.255
  gateway 20.0.0.2
  up route add -host 21.0.0.1  gw 20.0.0.2 dev eth1
  up route add -host 21.0.0.2  gw 20.0.0.2 dev eth1
  up route del default gw 20.0.0.2 eth1

# You want it like this:
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         20.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
20.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0

# on the peer
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         21.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
21.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

Once you have the VMs up and have configured a static route on each of those, you can use iperf with one end as a sink and the other as a source e.g.:

```
iperf -s
iperf -c 20.0.0.1 -t 10 -i 1
```

bridge script setup:

```
#
# Settings
#
INCLUDE_QEMU_AS_SCREEN=
A_TELNET_1=6661
A_NAME="A-VM"
A_MEMORY=1G

B_TELNET_1=6665
B_NAME="B-VM"
B_MEMORY=1G

A_DISK_IMAGE=.A.disk.img
B_DISK_IMAGE=.B.disk.img

A_PID=.A.pid
B_PID=.B.pid

A_CMD_1=.A.cmd.1
B_CMD_1=.B.cmd.1

#
# Run QEMU in background or foreground
#
if [ "$INCLUDE_QEMU_AS_SCREEN" != "" ]
then
    SCREEN_QEMU_A='screen -t "A-qemu"'
    SCREEN_QEMU_B='screen -t "B-qemu"'
else
    SCREEN_QEMU_A='bg'
    SCREEN_QEMU_B='bg'
fi

#
# Store logs locally and use the date to avoid losing old logs
#
LOG_DATE=`date "+%a_%b_%d_at_%H_%M"`
HOME=$(eval echo ~${SUDO_USER})
LOG_DIR=logs/$LOG_DATE
mkdir -p $LOG_DIR
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    LOG_DIR=/tmp/$LOGNAME/logs/$LOG_DATE
    mkdir -p $LOG_DIR
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        LOG_DIR=.
    fi
fi

LOG_DIR_TEST=$LOG_DIR
mkdir -p $LOG_DIR_TEST

#
# create the tap
#
echo
echo ================ create taps ================
sudo tunctl -b -u $LOGNAME -t $LOGNAME-tap1
sudo tunctl -b -u $LOGNAME -t $LOGNAME-tap2

#
# bring up the tap
#
echo
echo =============== bring up taps ===============
sudo ifconfig $LOGNAME-tap1 up
sudo ifconfig $LOGNAME-tap2 up

#
# show the tap
#
echo
echo =================== tap 1 ===================
ifconfig $LOGNAME-tap1
echo
echo =================== tap 4 ===================
ifconfig $LOGNAME-tap2

#
# create the bridge
#
sudo brctl addbr $LOGNAME-br1

#
# bring up the bridge
#
sudo ifconfig $LOGNAME-br1 1.1.1.1 up

#
# show my bridge
#
echo
echo =================== bridge 1 ===================
ifconfig $LOGNAME-br1
brctl show $LOGNAME-br1
brctl showmacs $LOGNAME-br1

#
# attach tap interface to bridge
#
sudo brctl addif $LOGNAME-br1 $LOGNAME-tap1
sudo brctl addif $LOGNAME-br1 $LOGNAME-tap2

SCRIPT_START="echo Starting..."
SCRIPT_EXIT="echo Exiting...; sleep 3"

cat >$A_CMD_1 <<%%%
$SCRIPT_START
script -f $LOG_DIR_TEST/VM-A -f -c 'telnet localhost $A_TELNET_1'
$SCRIPT_EXIT
%%%

cat >$B_CMD_1 <<%%%
$SCRIPT_START
script -f $LOG_DIR_TEST/VM-B -f -c 'telnet localhost $B_TELNET_1'
$SCRIPT_EXIT
%%%

chmod +x $A_CMD_1
chmod +x $B_CMD_1

run_qemu_in_screen_or_background()
{
    SCREEN=$1
    shift

    if [ "$SCREEN" = "bg" ]
    then
        $* &
    else
        $SCREEN $*
    fi
}

echo
echo
echo
echo "##########################################################"
echo "#                   Starting QEMU                        #"
echo "##########################################################"
echo
echo
echo

run_qemu_in_screen_or_background \
    $SCREEN_QEMU_A \
        qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic \
            -m $A_MEMORY \
            -enable-kvm \
            -drive file=$A_DISK_IMAGE,if=virtio,media=disk \
            -serial telnet:localhost:$A_TELNET_1,nowait,server \
            -net nic,model=e1000,vlan=21,macaddr=10:16:3e:00:01:12 \
            -net tap,ifname=$LOGNAME-tap1,vlan=21,script=no \
            -boot c \
            -pidfile $A_PID

run_qemu_in_screen_or_background \
    $SCREEN_QEMU_B \
        qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic \
            -m $B_MEMORY \
            -enable-kvm \
            -drive file=$B_DISK_IMAGE,if=virtio,media=disk \
            -serial telnet:localhost:$B_TELNET_1,nowait,server \
            -net nic,model=e1000,vlan=21,macaddr=30:16:3e:00:03:14 \
            -net tap,ifname=$LOGNAME-tap2,vlan=21,script=no \
            -boot c \
            -pidfile $B_PID

sleep 1

screen -t "$A_NAME"   sh -c "sh $A_CMD_1"
screen -t "$B_NAME"   sh -c "sh $B_CMD_1"

sleep 5

echo
echo
echo
echo "##########################################################"
echo "#                   Hit enter to quit                    #"
echo "##########################################################"
echo
echo
echo

read xx

cat $A_PID 2>/dev/null | xargs kill -9 2>/dev/null
rm -f $A_PID 2>/dev/null
cat $B_PID 2>/dev/null | xargs kill -9 2>/dev/null
rm -f $B_PID 2>/dev/null

rm -f $A_CMD_1 2>/dev/null
rm -f $B_CMD_1 2>/dev/null

sudo brctl delif $LOGNAME-br1 $LOGNAME-tap1
sudo brctl delif $LOGNAME-br1 $LOGNAME-tap2

sudo ifconfig $LOGNAME-br1 down

sudo brctl delbr $LOGNAME-br1

sudo ifconfig $LOGNAME-tap1 down
sudo ifconfig $LOGNAME-tap2 down

sudo tunctl -d $LOGNAME-tap1
sudo tunctl -d $LOGNAME-tap2
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your **`VM1`** and **`VM2`** have some active ISO-OSI-L2/L3 connectivity, so there is some transport available, a way better approach to setup process-to-process communication is to use some industry-proven messaging framework rather than to spend time to build just another ftp-c/s.

For sending / receiving anything ( incl. BLOBs alike the whole files ) try **ZeroMQ** or **nanomsg** libraries, as these are broker-less frameworks, have bindings for many programming languages ready & have genuine performance / low latency.

Any distributed process-to-process systems projects will benefit from early adoption and using this approach.

Check http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:fileio3 to get some additional insights about additional add-on benefits alike load-balancing, failure-recovery et al.

As per your Q1: FTP servers, per-se, report the file transfer times. In ZeroMQ you can pragrammatically measure amount of time spent on file transfer as a distance between the two timestamps

As per your Q2: for ZeroMQ use any port allowed ( not restricted ) in Ubuntu